# Cordova Mobile To Mobile Communication Without Server?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webrtc

I'd like to exchange information between multiple clients on the same network, preferably without a server. Think chat room.

I was looking into https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc and other rtc based libraries and even though they do p2p communication they initially have to connect to a signaling server.

My app can assume all users are on the same network. Is there a way to send messages between these mobile users without a server? And if so what technology? (doesn't have to be rtc).

Comment: Have a look at sockets. There is a chrome plugin for that.

Answer (score 0):

@foreyez,
it is possible to do webrtc without a server, but most examples do NOT show it. Here is a link to two webpages that have videos, that might help you.

- [All about WebRTC with Chris Wilson, Ben Strong, and Dan Ristic](http://www.meetup.com/sfhtml5/events/132166572/)
- [WebRTC @ SFHTML5](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILM4q-aaVpYgRM5XTCnQuVt)

If you see the name Chris Wilson again, watch his videos. He does the best job of explaining it. He works for Google.

Best of Luck.